# Mapsforge .map output from QGIS

Tags: qgis, export, file-formats, mapsforge, oruxmaps

Is there any way to output Mapsforge `.map`-files from QGIS?

I am trying to create a map to be displayed by OruxMaps, and Mapsforge seems to be the best format to use but I am not an expert.

Currently I use the Processing Toolbox to create Raster Tiles (MBtiles), but the resulting files are inconveniently large (GB) for a single state.